# Using ID in session after successful login

Tags: php, session

I have found one tutorial for login/register form in google. The problem is that I can't understand how to work with sessions and especially how to use the ID of logged user. So this is the login form.

```
<form id="login-form" action="login.php" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Потребителско име" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" tabindex="1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Парола" tabindex="3">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="5">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Login.php

```
//check if already logged in move to home page
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: userAction.php'); } 

//process login form if submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];

if($user->login($username,$password,$id)){ 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;   
} else {
    header('Location: userAction.php');
    $_SESSION['errMsg'] = 'Wrong username/password';

}
```

}
And this is the user class

```
class User extends Password{

private $_db;

function __construct($pdo){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_db = $pdo;
}

private function get_user_hash($username){  

    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        return $row['password'];

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
}

public function login($username,$password){

    $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

    if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed) == 1){

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;          
        return true;
    }   
}

public function logout(){
    session_destroy();
}

public function is_logged_in(){
    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
        return true;
    }       
}

}
```

So everything work just fine. I can register and login without any problems. Also I can call `$_SESSION['username']` whenever I want but I want to use also `userid` with `$_SESSION['userid']`..

May be is something easy but can't understand what and where I should put.

Edit:
This is how they look now: `user.php`

```
    public function login_user_id($username){  

    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT id,email FROM users WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

       // $row = $stmt->fetch();

        return $row = $stmt->fetch();

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
}
```

and this is the login.php

```
    if($user->login($username,$password)){ 

$data=$user->login_user_id($username);
foreach($data as $row)
{
    $row['id'] = $_SESSION['id'];// assing user_id to session
    $row['email'] = $_SESSION['email'];


}
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;

}
```

Comment: `get_user_hash` shoud select userId , and save that also to session like username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After matching password you need to get the id of logging user's

```
if($user->login($username,$password)){ 
    $user_id=$user->login_user_id($username);// get user id
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;// assing user_id to session
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;   
}
```

Getting user_id according to username from database

```
function login_user_id($username){  

    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        return $row['user_id'];

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: That's work. And what if I want to use also name, birth date and so on. Need to make it like this in function for everything I need?

Comment: Then change your query to `SELECT user_id,name, birth date `  and using loop extract you data and ass into session

Comment: And then how will become this `$row = $stmt->fetch(); return $row['user_id'];` ?

Comment: return `$row = $stmt->fetch();` and use loop

Comment: Can you show with simple example? `$row = $stmt->fetch();` then `foreach ($row as $results){ // here what? }`

Comment: check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) and [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) you can use also fetch_assoc

Comment: So something like `foreach ... { $row['id'] = $_SESSION['id']; $row['name'] = $_SESSION['name'];` and so on.. ?

Comment: Okay. Thank's for the help!

Comment: One last thing - after `foreach` loop do I need `return` something? `return $row` or no?

Comment: `$data=$user->login_user_id($username); foreach($data as $row){extract you data}` and return `$row = $stmt->fetch();`

Comment: But this in login.php or in the user class where is the function.

Comment: in login .php `$data=$user->login_user_id($username); foreach($data as $row){extract you data}` and user class `return $row = $stmt->fetch();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87955/discussion-between-saty-and-jason-paddle).

Answer (score 1):

You need to chang two functions

```
private function get_user_hash($username){  

        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password,id FROM users WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            return $row;

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

public function login($username,$password){

    $hashed = $this->get_user_hash($username);

    if($this->password_verify($password,$hashed['password']) == 1){

        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true; 
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $hashed['id']; 
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I can't login whit this way.